# Bedienungsanleitung – Alternative zur Überschrift »Für Eilige«

Tags: phrase-request

Ich schreibe an einer Art Anleitung, der ein Abschnitt für Nutzer vorangestellt ist, die nicht die Zeit oder Muße haben, sich durch die Anleitung zu arbeiten.
In diesem wird eine Methode beschrieben, gewisse Ziele ohne große Arbeit, aber mit gewissen Mängeln zu erreichen.
Diese Methode hat nichts mit den im Rest der Anleitung beschriebenen Verfahren zu tun.

Zur Veranschaulichung stelle man sich eine Reparaturanleitung für ein beliebiges technisches Gerät vor.
Die eigentliche Anleitung erklärt, wie man das Gerät zerlegt, verschiedene Komponenten auf ihre Funktionsfähigkeit überprüft, usw.
Der Abschnitt, um den es geht, erwähnt die Möglichkeit, dem Gerät einen beherzten Tritt zu geben.

**Ich suche nun eine passende Überschrift für diesen Abschnitt.** Diese kann, muss aber nicht enthalten, dass die beschriebene Methode Mängel hat.

*Schnelleinstieg, Kurzanleitung* o. Ä. scheiden aus, da die Methode nichts mit den im Rest der Anleitung beschriebenen Verfahren zu tun hat und dementsprechend keinen Einstieg oder eine Übersicht bietet.
Meine beste Lösung bisher ist *Für Eilige,* welches mir aber unnötig abwertend gegenüber dem Anwender der beschriebenen Methode ist.

Comment: Brevi manu. &nbsp;

Comment: I'm feeling lucky!

Comment: Du findest "Eilige" abwertend?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Für Eilige" klingt irgendwie komisch, aber ich hatte mal eine Anleitung für einen Zauberwürfel, die war überschrieben mit:

> Für Ungeduldige

Das passt sicher am besten zu deiner Frage.

Comment: "Alternative Methode für Ungeduldige" wäre noch ein wenig genauer (dafür nicht so griffig).

Answer (score 9):

Mir fallen noch

**Expressvariante** und **Wenn's dringend ist**

als mögliche Überschriften ein. Sollte "-variante" nicht in Deinen Kontext passen, bin ich mir sicher, dass sich mit "Express-" etwas basteln lässt.

Der Frage erster Absatz lässt an Kombinationen mit "Zeit" denken:

**Bei Zeitnot / Keine Zeit? / Wenn die Zeit fehlt** usw.

oder auch

**Wenn's schnell gehen muss**,

wobei längere Konstruktionen mMn aufgesetzt wirken.

Answer (score 6):

"Abkürzung" oder "Umleitung" mit einem passenden kleinen Bildchen beschreiben vielleicht das, was du suchst: ein schnellerer, aber nicht gleichwertiger Weg.

Wenn du den Leser mehr ansprechen möchtest, vielleicht: "Für Mutige ohne Zeit"

Answer (score 5):

Da gäbe es jede Menge Möglichkeiten

- Auf einen Blick
- Zusammengefasst
- Im Überblick
- Exzerpt
- Kurz & bündig
- In aller Kürze

...
In Anbetracht des negativen Kontextes: 
Wie wäre es mit »Auf die Schnelle«?

Comment: Und alle treffen sie nicht zu – siehe den zweiten Absatz meiner Frage.

Comment: Wrzlprmft, dann solltest Du aber schon in deiner Frage umschreiben um was es sich handelt, damit wir gezielter antworten können. Ohne mehr Beschreibung/Präzisierung hätte ich auch `"Kurz und bündig"` vorgeschlagen.  Texten wir dich mit Worten und Phrasen zu und Du pickst dann das passende.  Bei Stackoverflow wäre diese Frage im negativen Wertebereich und hätte ein `[Mainly opinion based]` flag. ;)

Comment: @try-catch-finally: Welche Antwort der Fragesteller akzeptiert, ist immer »maily opinion based«, was aber nicht heißt, dass die Frage das ist. Außerdem gelten hier (wie auch auf diversen anderen Stack-Exchanges) andere Richtlinien diesbezüglich. Was die Präzisierung betrifft schrieb ich, dass »die Methode nichts mit den im Rest der Anleitung beschriebenen Verfahren zu tun hat«. Dieser Satz alleine schließt alle Vorschläge dieser Antwort klar aus.

Answer (score 4):

Das, was du beschreibst, entspricht ziemlich genau dem, was ich mit „Quick-and-dirty“ bezeichnen würde. Steht zwar (noch) nicht im Duden, aber wenn ich vom Zielpublikum mindestens rudimentäre Englischkenntnisse erwarten kann, dann würde ich das tatsächlich auch so nennen. (Oder eine Alternativschreibung „Quick’n’dirty“).

„Für Eilige“ finde ich im übrigen nicht so schlecht; die von dir erwähnte Abwertung empfinde ich eigentlich so nicht.

Oder wie wär’s mit „Nicht für jedermann!“, in Anlehnung an H.Hesse ;-)

Comment: +1 dafür dass "für Eilige" nicht abwertend ist.

Answer (score 3):

Auf gut Glück!

```
<!-- (Body must at least be 30 chars). -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Ich finde „Für Eilige“ super als Überschrift. Wenn ich das sehe, weiß ich genau:

- Der Autor hat das absichtlich so formuliert und erkannt, dass ich in genau meiner Situation schnelle Hilfe brauche
- Gründliches und sauberes Arbeiten wird das wohl nicht sein, was jetzt folgt
- Der folgende Text enthält nicht die ganze Wahrheit
- Wenn’s schiefgeht, habe ich ja immer noch Plan B
- Der Autor hat lange geknobelt, um diese Formulierung zu finden, denn es gibt wohl kaum eine kürzere Beschreibung, die so punktgenau trifft

Answer (score -1):

Vielleicht passt

> Schnelleinstieg

Hängt natürlich davon ab, worum es im Einzelnen geht

Comment: Ein "vielleicht" hält der Ablehnung seitens des Fragestellers (im 2. Absatz) nicht stand.